# Passwords for newly created users?

Tags: ubuntu, users, password, authentication, postgresql

I am fairly new to Linux and I have question regarding users. When I use the `useradd` command I don't specify a password. I must use the `passwd` command afterwards. Does this mean that the user is disabled until it is done?

I installed Postgresql with the `apt-get` command. Do I have to create a postgres-user and change ownership of the installed postgresql files? Or is this taken care of by the `apt-get`?

I see that the owner of some of the files is already `postgres`. However, how do I run the server as `postgres`? I don't know the password. Trying to do `su postgres` fails because of authentication failure.

Comment: @chirp Entries in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` etc. are separated by `:`. The second entry contains the password hash, so if it is something like `!`, `NP`, `*` or anything else that isn't a valid result of the hash function used by your system, you will *not* be able to login with *any* password, since no input on your part can result in a hash like `!`.

Comment: @n.st just when I wanted to correct my typo… deleted my comment… what n.st said is correct. Sorry for messing this up…

Answer (score 3):

> When I use the useradd command I don't specify a password. [...] Does this mean that the user is disabled until it is done?

Yes, if you don't specify a password hash using `useradd`'s option `-p`, password-based login to the newly created account will be locked until you set a password using `passwd`.

> I installed Postgresql with the `apt-get` command. Do I have to create a postgres-user and change ownership of the installed postgresql files? Or is this taken care of by the apt-get?

The `.deb` packages `apt-get` downloads and allows you to install usually come with a script that takes care of all settings required by the program you are installing.

> Trying to do `su postgres` fails because of authentication failure.

As Stefan already [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103289/28235), run `su postgres` as root, e.g. by running `sudo su postgres` and entering *your* password.

Answer (score 3):

> I installed Postgresql with the apt-get command. Do I have to create a
>   postgres-user and change ownership of the installed postgresql files?

No, you don't need to create `postgre-user`, `postgresql` package will automatically create the users that require.

You can check using :
`getent passwd postgres`
or just `grep` in `/etc/passwd` file

---

> I see that the owner of some of the files is already postgres.
>   However, how do I run the server as postgres? I don't know the
>   password. Trying to do su postgres fails because of authentication
>   failure.

- You don't need to set password for system account
- if postgres user already exists before installing package then `useradd` command will take care of that ( it will change uid below 500 for making it system user see `man 5 adduser.conf` for more info ).
- in Debian based system the `start-stop-daemon` utility, which handles pid-files, changing the user, putting the daemon into background and much more, So postgresql will start by `postgres` user which is define in init scirpt or postgres cluster binary itself.

in RHEL based system you will see below line for starting postgresql with postgres user :

`su -l postgres -c '/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl start -s -l /var/postgresql/log -D /usr/local/pgsql/data'`

Answer (score 1):

```
stefan@laptop ~  $ su -
Password: 
laptop ~ # useradd example
laptop ~ # su example
example@laptop /root $ exit
laptop ~ # logout
stefan@laptop ~  $ su example
Password:
```

The user can only be logged in as root without a password.

To log in as the postgre user try to su as root (if you have root).

So try a:

```
sudo su postgres
```

and that should work.

Comment: Or use `sudo -i`. Also they are not logged in as root, rather you're setting user (`su`) to this other user. You can mimic logging in as this user using `su - example` too. Using `su example` doesn't read all of their shell's configuration files from `/home/example`.

Comment: Okey. So to be postgres I must have root access?

Comment: You need the ability to either become root, or `sudo su - postreges`. Admins generally don't like to give out root's password, `sudo` allows users to elevate their credentials w/o having to know root's password.